# Unable to install R base and RStudio in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, rstudio

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.4.4-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.4-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[image: screenshot of terminal commands]

Comment: Why install packages for 16.04 in 18.04? That is likely to cause problems.

Comment: Please do not send screenshots of terminal, prefer to copy paste console outputs as text, formatted with {}

Comment: As well as being the wrong release (xenial) it also looks like you are trying to install a package of the wrong architecture (i386) - which the system is (sensibly) refusing to do as it apparently requires removal of the native `sudo` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [R Studio documentation](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/), you must run install commands as root with `sudo`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter3.5
sudo apt-get install -y r-base
sudo apt-get install -y gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.1.453-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.1.453-amd64.deb
```